# Weird trick for simplified substitution of derivatives in physical models

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-modeling

I am solving the equations describing the reaction in a tubular reactor where terms reading something like this show up:
$$\frac{d}{dz} \dot{n}_i  = \frac{d}{dz} u c_i.  $$
Here $u$ denotes velocity and $c$ concentration.
Now by the chain rule I can write it as
$$u \frac{d}{dz} c_i + c_i \frac{d}{dz} u$$
and all is fine. However, the term $\frac{d}{dz} u $ is nonzero and extremely hard to close since velocity depends on a lot of parmateters (i.e. by the ideal gas law) which further down the line explodes into a mess of derivative terms that are again hard to close by themselves.

As an engineer I was told the following "technique", which I know is questionable at least, but I can not find any reference to any name or underlying assumption as to what is going on. So here's the trick:

When solving this equation in a ODE solver, we first omit the term containing $\frac{d}{dz} u $. Thereby we are not obeying differentiation rules, obviously. To not be too wrong though, we calculate $u$ at every position $z$ from known values (which is significantly easier then carying around the gradients). So basically we neglect the gradient but somehow explicitly do consider $u$ changing over $z$ This approach is often implemented but never documented. I only realized how wrong it is when working on a problem like this myself. I was never told why or how we do it and most of my colleagues experience this too.

Does this have a name? Is it valid under certain conditions? If so, when?
Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It seems if you're using an ODE solver you could start with $\dot{n}_i(t,z) = u(t,z)c_i(t,z) + f_i(t)$, where $f$ would have to come from some sort of boundary conditions.